# How do I get a list of URLs using lxml's start-with() if they are relative links?

Tags: python, lxml

I'm looking at making a list of URLs that contains "page.php"? Do I parse all the links and then loop through them or is there a better way?

The URLs look like this:

```
 <a href="../path/page.php?something=somewhere&yes=no">
```

And I tried this:

```
resumes = doc.xpath('//a[starts-with(@href, "../path/page.php"]/text()')
```

Is this correct or should I be using the absolute URL with starts-with()?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way, provided you want **all** links containing page.php

```
links = doc.findall('.//a') # Finds all links
resume = [res for res in links if 'page.php' in res.text_content()]
```

First, I get all the links on the page, then I make a list of all the links with page.php in them.

This is untested (I don't  have all your code so I can't test it as quick as usual) but should still work.